# Why request.user == 'admin' conditional statement not working in Django3 views.py?

Tags: django, django-views

I am currently logged as 'admin' in my django3 project. As 'admin', I have to display all the books. But the `if-else` statement in the views.py is not recognising the 'admin' and always goes into the `else` section of the conditional statement.

```
def book_list(request):
    print ('Currently logged as ', request.user)
    if request.user == 'admin':
        print ('All')
        books = Book.objects.all()
    else:
        print ('Filter')
        books = Book.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    return render(request, 'mtsAuthor/book_list.html', {
        'books': books
    })
```

When I refresh the page as an 'admin', the following custom debug messages are seen in the terminal. Hope the same shall help to troubleshoot.

```
Currently logged as  admin
Filter
[25/Feb/2021 13:39:45] "GET /mtsAuthor/books/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9363  
[25/Feb/2021 13:39:45] "GET /media/books/covers/_DSC0179.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if request.user.is_superuser
```

Comment: Thanks! But wondering why the if-else is working strange?

Comment: Because it doesn't know what to judge, you have to give it a attributes like usernname, is_active, request.user is Instance.

Comment: @chandra if-else is working strange because `request.user` is a dictionary. You are comparing a dict-like object with a string object of value "admin". Try `print(dict(request.user))` to see the value.

Comment: `request.user` is not a dictionary it's a `User` instance, the "strangeness" is because you were comparing a `User` instance to a string (actually you were comparing the ids of a `User` instance and a string)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check it based on username:

```
if request.user.username = 'admin'
```

And if you want to check it based on superuser:

```
if request.user.is_superuser
```